# Android get Travels Companies List from APIs(Google API or Any)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2

- Hello All, I am new in Android Development,
- My requirement is getting Travels Company List from current Location[please find the Image]
- am able to get current Location and showing Map in Android App Home page.
- Is there any other party API or **Google API will give current Locations Travels List**
- Please help me on this,[please update Google API if available]
- thanks in Advance.[image: TravelsList]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Places API nearby search to get a list of travel agencies. You should execute HTTP request like

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=25.597295%2C85.118716&radius=2000&type=travel_agency&key=YOUR_API_KEY

and parse response in your Android app.

To get more details about Places API searches please refer to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Hope it helps!